# Removing certain elements form a list of lists

Tags: r, list, loops, foreach

I am working on a `list` object containing hundreds of "lists" of random integers in the following format:

```
assignments <- list(
  as.integer(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3)),
  as.integer(c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3)),
  as.integer(c(1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2)),
  as.integer(c(1, 2, 0, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2))
)

[[1]]
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3

[[2]]
 [1] 1 1 1 0 0 0 3 3

[[3]]
[1] 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2

[[4]]
[1] 1 2 0 3 2 3 2 2 2
```

from which to extract the most frequent "non-zero" integer from a given list. However, in some lists of this `list` object, zero appears to be the most frequent integer, such as the second list `[[2]]`. The created some problems on my analysis.

Is there anyway to loop through a list of lists to remove certain elements, such as zero, from each list of this big list?

One method I've experimented earlier was to loop through this list of lists and use `!=` to exclude values that equal zero

```
for(i in assignments){i[i != 0]}
```

but this didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lapply(assignments,function(x) x[x!=0])
```

Comment: You are welcome = )  `assignments=lapply(assignments,function(y) as.data.table(count(y[y!=0]))[freq==max(freq),x])` This code gives you the most frequent non-zero integer(s) for each sub list